# JTable getValueAt method cast to Integer exception

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I use this code to get my ID number of my `JTable`,

But `"AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ClassCastException` occur,

```
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if (e.getSource() == dellButton) {
        try {
            int rowToDelete = 0;
            int rowToModel = 0;
            if (table.getSelectedRow() > -1) {
                rowToDelete = table.getSelectedRow();
                rowToModel = table.convertRowIndexToModel(rowToDelete);
                tableModel.removeRow(rowToModel);
            }
        } catch (SQLException sqle) {
            sqle.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

My `TableModel.removeRow()` method:

```
...
    public void removeRow(int rowNumber) throws SQLException {
    String removeQuery = "delete from mytable where id=?";
    PreparedStatement pStatement = con.prepareStatement(removeQuery);
    pStatement.setInt(1, rowNumber);
    int rowsAffected = pStatement.executeUpdate();
}
...
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- `int rowID = (int) table.getValueAt(selectedRowIndex, 0);` is useless code line,
- code line `tableModel.removeRow(rowID, rowIndex);` has wrong paramaters
- test if any row is selected, otherwise selected row returns -1
- everything could be only

  ```
  @Override
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
      int rowToDelete = 0;
      int rowToModel = 0;
      if (table.getSelectedRow() > -1) {
          rowToDelete = table.getSelectedRow();
          rowToModel = table.convertRowIndexToModel(rowToDelete);
          model.removeRow(rowToModel);
      }
  }
  ```
- be sure that your `SelectionMode` will be, otherwise you would need to loop inside arrays of selected rows,

  ```
  table.getSelectionModel().setSelectionMode(
              ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);
  ```

Comment: The JTable expert speaks. 1+

Comment: +1, especially for the first statement. You don't need to access data to remove the row from the DefaultTableModel.

Comment: So nice code, But by attention to my model `removeRow` method, there is problem yet...

Comment: I write my model `removeRow` method, to delete row by each line id. My table has two column, `ID` and `Name`.

Comment: You wrote your removeRow() method incorrectly. There is no need to know the rowID in order to delete the row from the model. All you need to know is the row number that is selected. Use the DefaultTableModel as has been suggested to you many times before. It has all the functionality that you need. Learn how to use it first before attempting to write a custom model.

Comment: @camickr I update my code, Now How change it? (I use database)

Comment: @Sajjad aaachh I see you would needed to manage JDBC side, and  if passed then you can to remove row from model, no idea whats your SQL Engine, but in TableModel to override getColumnClass to Integer, for huge numbers to use Long then getValueAt, for real answer to post an SSCCE, short, runnable, compilable, with hardcoded value for TableModel, btw some of SQL interpreters can pass String via JDBC to int with success,

Comment: This question is going from bad to worse.

Comment: @Hovercraft Full Of Eels do you know [accepted answers isn't possible to delete](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14932/allow-author-of-accepted-answer-to-delete-it-in-certain-circumstances),

Comment: @mKorbel Why you want to delete answer?

Comment: @Sajjad your question missing a few details, your question is your mirror, every your edit changed its ..., I'm always upvoted OPs that accepted my post, seeee

Comment: @mKorbel i have to create a new post to my question about my removeRow method!